# How to check if css class is implemented in website or not?

Tags: html, css

We are doing POC in which we ask client to add just the script tag in there website. The script tag refers to the javascript file in our website. When our script tag gets executed we inject the HTML code in the Parent website using the location of script tag.

The HTML code we injected, contains css classes which do not have any definition in our site and hence it gets the inherited css of basic HTML tags from the parent site.

The problem is how to check if parent site has classes implemented in there stylesheet file so that if there are no classes defined in parent site then we can add default definitions for our classes.

Example:
Let's say our injected HTML code snippet contains the following div.

```
<p>Property Details</p>
```

Lets say **parent site** has css definition for

tag like below

```
p
{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

And lets say we refered our own css file path, which also has the definition for

like below

```
p
{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**(Note: stylesheet reference of parent site will always be above the stylesheet reference of our HTML code snippet.)**

In above case style of

should be with font size 16px and font weight bold, which is defined in parent site css file.

But in case, parent site css file does not have a definition for

then style of

should be background yellow, which is defined in our HTML code snippet.

Comment: You can access your stylesheets with `document.styleSheets` and find all properties defined in them, but unless your stylesheet is small I think you should find a better way to achieve what you want to.

Comment: Hi there, thank you to both of you for giving the time, can we do something like this, can we write p:not-defined {background-color: yellow;} in injected HTML code snippet, so that if the definition of css for p tag is not present in document then only apply yellow background?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (as suggested by Cray in the comments)

```js
function isDefined(selector) {
  for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = document.styleSheets[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < sheet.cssRules.length; j++) {
      return sheet.cssRules[j].selectorText == selector;
    }
  }
}

var styleElement = document.createElement("style");
styleElement.type = 'text/css';
document.head.appendChild(styleElement);

var myStylesheet = document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length - 1];

if (!isDefined("p")) {
  myStylesheet.insertRule("p { background-color: yellow; }")
}

if (!isDefined("h1")) {
  myStylesheet.insertRule("h1 { background-color: yellow; }")
}
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<h1>hello</h1>
<p>world</p>
```

This is a simple example, but you'll need to expand it if you want to deal with cases in which the client defines a `p.class-name` or `div p` selector.
Note that since these selectors have higher precedence, the client could override your changes as a workaround.